# Object not instantiating properly

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I am currently using VS2015 for this.

I am trying to create a binary search tree in c++ so that I can learn both the language and the data structure while trying to see if I can follow good practices. However, I am coming through a problem where I am not properly instantiating the object properly in the driver file.

BSTHeader.h

```
#pragma once

/*
    Properties of Binary Search Tree:

    1.) Elements less than root will go to the left child of root
    2.) Elements greater than root will go to the right child of root
*/

#include <memory>

// Binary Search Tree handler class
class BSTHeader {

    /*
        Naive implementation of BSTNode (non-generic version)

        Nested class is private, but it's internal fields and member functions 
        are public to outer class: BSTHeader
    */
    class BSTNode {
    public:
        int data;
        std::unique_ptr<BSTNode> left;
        std::unique_ptr<BSTNode> right;

        BSTNode(int val) {
            data = val;
            left = NULL;
            right = NULL;
        }
        ~BSTNode() {}
    };

    std::unique_ptr<BSTNode> root;           // Root of BST
    unsigned int size;                       // Total amount of nodes in tree from root


public:
    BSTHeader();
    BSTHeader(int val);
    ~BSTHeader();
    bool insert(std::unique_ptr<BSTNode>& root, int val);
}
```

BSTHeader.cpp

```
#include "BSTHeader.h"


/*
    Constructors:
*/
BSTHeader::BSTHeader() {
    root = NULL;
    size = 0;
}

BSTHeader::BSTHeader(int val) {
    root = std::unique_ptr<BSTNode>(new BSTHeader::BSTNode(val));       // Smart pointer to an internal BSTNode
    size = 1;
}

BSTHeader::~BSTHeader() {}                                              // Empty destructor from use of smart pointer 

/*
    Member functions:
*/
bool BSTHeader::insert(std::unique_ptr<BSTNode>& root, int val) {
    if (root == NULL) {                                                 // Place new element here
        root = std::unique_ptr<BSTNode>(new BSTHeader::BSTNode(val));
        size++;
        return true;
    }

    if (val < root.get()->data) {                                       // val < root
        insert(root.get()->left, val);
    }

    else if (val > root.get()->data) {                                  // val > root
        insert(root.get()->right, val);
    }
```

The issue I get is here, where I believe I am trying to instantiate a BSTHeader object.

Program.cpp

```
#include "BSTHeader.h"

int main()
{
    BSTHeader::BSTHeader bst();   // <----- ERROR
    return 0;
}
```

The error I am getting is `cannot determine which instance of overloaded function "BSTHeader:BSTHeader" is intended`

However, whenever I do:
`BSTHeader bst()`
I am not able to access the `insert(..., ...)` function for the object doing `bst.insert(..., ...)` due to `expression must have class type` even though the error above does not appear.

Yet everything works fine and I am able to access all the member methods by doing this: `BSTHeader bst(5)` by using the overloaded constructor.

I am not sure whether its a namespace issue or not. I feel as though I am missing something.

Comment: Your error line is the _Most Vexing Parse_.  It looks like a function prototype, so that's what it is interpreted as.  Remove the `()`.

Comment: That fixed it, but does this mean that I should never include a () for accessing the default constructor?

Comment: @Naz Yep. You may use `{}` instead if you want to. but you should probably just leave it out.

Comment: Don't use `NULL` in modern C++. Use `nullptr` instead.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I was debating that, but I chose `NULL` only because I thought that the smartpointer object itself isn't actually a pointer to a smartpointer. Wasn't sure that `nullptr` also works for non-pointer objects. But thanks for that reference, will read up on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
BSTHeader::BSTHeader bst();   // <----- ERROR
```

is a declaration of a function named `bst` that takes no arguments and returns a `BSTHeader::BSTHeader`.

This is known as the "most vexing parse", and often described in less polite language.

If you want to instantiate an instance, giving the constructor no arguments, remove the `()`.